# Pause and resume thread drawing to SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing a chess game for Android (http://androidchess.appspot.com), using `SurfaceView` for the chessboard. I have a drawing `Thread`, that draws the chessboard in a loop. The problem is that when there are no active animations (this is more that 90% of time), it makes no sense to waste CPU and battery for drawing. How should I solve this? Maybe somehow pausing and resuming the drawing `Thread`?

Comment: @fhucho I have a simple example for you... see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (you can test it by trying [this code](http://pastie.org/878656)):

```
final Object monitor = new Object();

class Drawing implements Runnable
{
    @override
    void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {

            synchronized(monitor)
            {
                monitor.wait();
            }

            // draw
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // start your thread
    while(true)
    {
        if( needRefresh )
        {
            synchronized(monitor)
            {
                monitor.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend using a [Semaphore](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) if you want to signal once and then keep drawing (i.e. do not block) until the signal is turned off.

Comment: Thanks, wait/notify is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered the question yourself. You should pause your drawing thread when nothing is rendered. When using the OpenGL SurfaceView you can also use an immediate mode (which draws continuously) or manual (draw by request).

Comment: But how exactly should I pause/resume the thread? The Thread.suspend() is deprecated according to Android's documentation.

Comment: the above approach from lirik would work i presume. Another more modern approach would be to use the java concurrency classes in combination with a Lock/Condition or similar approaches.